# Ubuntu 18.04 Can't boot: Create Volatile files and Directories hangs

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

I couldn't boot due to this problem, I managed to boot in recovery mode (grub advanced options for Ubuntu) and empty the /tmp directory as suggested here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463224/how-to-understand-the-a-start-job-is-running-for-create-volatile-files-and-dire) and could boot normally (can't tell how many files there where in /tmp, there could be lots of them since I installed lots of things), but the next boot gave me the same error and now I can't even boot in recovery mode, so I don't have access to the shell. Any ideas about the cause of the problem and its resolution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was that I didn't clear /tmp correctly, and there were something like 1 million directories (pwntool disasm function creates a directory in /tmp, the more you know..). I booted ubuntu live from usb, mounted the filesystem, renamed tmp to tmp2, created tmp, booted normally and deleted tmp2 (took something like 2 hours..).

Comment: could you elaborate more on what do you mean that you did not clear /tmp correctly?

Comment: Jekins left a ton of tmp files and recreating the tmp folder worked for me. It's very easy if you use Ubuntu desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I rebooted one of my Ionos (formerly 1and1) cloud servers running on Ubuntu 16.04. Emptying /tmp fixed the problem but I first had to figure out how to access the /tmp directory since I could not boot into the system (even in recovery mode). This solution is specific to anyone using Ionos cloud servers using the Knoppix Data Recovery DVD but it may apply with other hosts as well:

1. Load the Knoppix Data Recovery DVD and reboot (I'm assuming any "live" DVD option would work here, so if you don't have Knoppix, try using another option)
2. Run `$ su` in the command-line to gain admin privileges
3. Run `# vg` to display the volume group to be mounted
4. You'll see something like the following:

> root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# vgs run/lvm/lvmetad
> .socket: connect failed:
> No such file or directory WARNING
> : Failed to connect to lvmetad.
> Falling back to internal scanning VG
> #PV #LV #SN Attr VSize VFree vg00
> 1 2 0 wz--n- 79.52g 0

5. The volume you are looking for is 'vgXX' (or something similar).
6. Switch to this volume: `root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# vgchange -ay vg00`
7. Run the following to determine which volume group your data is in `root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# lvdisplay`. It will likely display two or more groups, choose the one that is closest in size to your logical volume ("lv01" or something similar, usually the larger of the two)
8. Now mount the volume group `root@Microknoppix:/home/knoppix# mount /dev/vg00/lv01 /mnt/old`
9. Make sure you have the right volume mounted `ls /mnt/old/`. If you are in the right place, it will display all your root directories. If not, try a different volume
10. Now delete the files in /tmp (be careful with this step! You don't want to delete the wrong directories/files) `rm -r /mnt/old/tmp/*`. This is the safer option but it will take you a long time to complete since it asks for confirmation for each step. The faster way is this (again, be careful!) `rm -rf /mnt/old/tmp/*`
11. Eject the DVD and reboot your server as usual.
    Hope this helps!